# Android: Navigation drawer and audio player

Tags: android, audio, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer, navigation-drawer

I am developing an application using navigation drawer, having a drawer contains 3 items, and one fragment. On selection of item from list of drawer, according data is displayed in fragment.

I used the example as same as given in [This Link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/)

Now what i want to do in the same example i used above is :

**1. Customize action bar as : Remove app icon, and change the title text color and background, keep the navigation toggle button as it is.**

**2. Play audio in fragment. Audio files are in raw folder. Buttons are : Play, Pause, Stop, Seek bar.**

**3. 3 audio files should be in raw folder and on the basis of selection respective audio should play.**

I am done with play audio in activity, but i am not able to play audio in fragment, and accordingly depends on selection of items.

I am in middle of my application and struct due to issues. Please guide me what should i do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question and you have probably resolved this issue so let me know if was helpful.

To play audio in a fragment you just copy this code:

```
final MediaPlayer sound1 = new MediaPlayer;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

ImageView play1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
    play1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View play1)
        {       
         sound1=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.playsound);   
         sound1.start();     
        }                   
});




return rootView;

}
}
```